# Does "Delete files and directory" following symbolic links by recursivly activation?

Tags: install4j

For our purpose on windows systems we creating symbolic links inside the installation directory to point to directories outside the installation directory. It's necessary to place files we don't want to be touched during uninstall process but can be handled as normal files without configuring in our main application. Now we had the issues that during deinstallation by using the *Delete files and directory*-action all the files in the destination directory of our symbolic links were also be deleted. It's not the behaviour we expected. So my question is why are symbolic links handled like directory and why is this action following symbolic links? Maybe it could be an improvement to let the user configure the behaviour of handling symbolic links for these action? Or these action should not delete any files outside the installation directory undepended whether it is a symbolic link or a normal directory/file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, Unix and macOS, none of the recursive file actions (copy, delete ...) follow symbolic links. The installer uses the NIO API to determine if a directory is a symbolic link and does not recurse into it if this is the case.

For Windows, install4j 7.0.4 and lower do not detect symbolic links, this will be fixed in 7.0.5.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug? I tried out with the _hello world_ sample by extending it with one directory in the fileset (e.g. `external-stuff`) and the delete action in the uninstall section configured with recursive action right before the finish screen. After installation I manually created two or more symbolic links inside the `external-stuff` directory with the command `mklink /D <linkname> <target-dir>`. Also I placed some dummy files to the target directories of the symbolic links. After deinstallation, all files are gone. The sample was made by 7.0.4 but our effected product uses version 6.1.5.

Comment: Indeed, symbolic links on Windows were not handled. This will be fixed in 7.0.5. Please write to support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.